Finding maximum transfers possible for a list of employees and their preferences
I want to find maximum transfers possible for a set of employees and their location preferences.
Help with algo regarding maximum transfers possible
I have a data (following structure) which denotes transfer requests of employees from one state to other state.
Employee_ID, From_State, To_State, Place_Since
I need to arrive at maximum number of transfers possible for the data. Transfers need to be done based on seniority of place_since date. In case of tie in date, employee_id with higher number will get preference.
At the end number of employees transferred out from a state need to match the number of employees transferred in to a state.
How do I model/approach this problem?

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please note that we will not solve the problem for you, we would rather help you fixing or enhancing your current solution. As it stands, this question is not suitable for stackoverflow.
Please read https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems
